# How do i get specific data from a json data (api) using axios in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, facebook-graph-api, axios

I want to get a Image with spesific Text in caption from Instagram graph api.For example if caption from image has "yes" word in Instagram then must show in homepage.The problem is i know i cant write if promises in axios or maybe i dont know how to write this rule.thank you for your help.

```js
import React from 'react'
import '../styles/home.css'

import axios from 'axios';

export default class Home extends React.Component {
  state = {
    posts: []
  }

  componentDidMount() {
   axios.get(`https://graph.instagram.com/me/media?fields=id,caption,media_url,permalink,username&access_token=IGQ....`)
   
   .then(res => {
        const posts = res.data.data;
        this.setState({ posts });

        
      })

     

  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
       
        {
          this.state.posts
            .map(post =>
            <div className="banner_image">
              <img className="post_img" key={post.id} src={post.media_url} alt="image"/>
           <div className="banner_text">
             <div className="banner_content">
                {
                this.state.posts
                    .map(post =>
                    <h1 className="main_title" key={post.id}>{post.username}</h1>           
                    )
                }
                {this.state.posts
                    .map(post =>
                    <h3 className="main_caption" key={post.id}>{post.caption}</h3>
                
                    )
                }
             </div>
           </div>    
           </div>
            )
        }
        
        {
                this.state.posts
                    .map(post =>
                        <img className="post_img_food" key={post.id} src={post.media_url} alt="image"/>
                    )
                }
         
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try .indexOf and make a if statement that finds the string "yes" if its there it will display that picture if not elif or end.

```js
var caption = "This is some generic sentence that contains the word yes";
var substring = "yes";

console.log(caption.indexOf(substring) !== -1)
```

Comment: hmm somehow cant fetch with indexof :(

Comment: can you place tell me where to write this rule in code ??